# If second to last character is numeric

Tags: php, numeric

I would like to figure out, how to check if the second to last character of a string is numeric.

My string is:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The URL is something like: http://www.domain.com/2/,http://www.domain.com/3/ and so on..

Is it possible to figure out if a number exists at the end of the URL before the last back slash `/` ?

Something like:

```
if (is_numeric($url, second-to-last-character)) {
   // Do real stuff
} else {
   // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about regexes ?

```
if (!preg_match('#/\d+/?$#', $url))
    // There is no numeric at the end, abort !
```

I propose this because you won't know how many digits your id will have, so you can't just test the second-to-last character.

Comment: Thank you! The others answered my question corrrectly but you thought a little further! Very good. :)

Comment: Would have a slightly greater overhead - and goes beyond the original question, but this is the better solution IMO, except I'd add a `?` after that final trailing slash in the regexp `#/\d+/?$#` ... just in case the trailing slash is missing from the URL.

Answer (score 4):

```
$fullurl = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$last = $fullurl[count($fullurl)-1];
//echo $last;

if(is_int($last))
echo "integer";
else
echo "Not integer";
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `substr`.  You can use this to get the second to last character.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
is_numeric(substr($url, -2, 1);
```

Comment: Missing a closing parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_numeric(substr($url, -2,1) ) {
```

should do you, You dont need the regex

Comment: Really ? So how do you test 2-digits ids, etc. ?

Comment: He doesnt want that, he wants to know if the second to last is a digit, This will work if the number is /1000/ or /1/

Comment: And doesn't it look like the numbers are ids ? It's just the beginning of a problem.

Comment: And yeah, it will work with 1000, but also with AAA0, ***0, etc.

Comment: agreed, His question was second to last, Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

use `substr`

```
if(is_numeric(substr($url,-2,1))){
    //dosomething
}else{
   echo "Invalid URL!";
}
```

in `substr`, the first parameter is the string, the second one is the offset, if the offset is negative, it will start at the end and go backwards, and the last one is the length. If not specified, it will go to the end of the string. So if you wanted to get the last tow characters, you would do `substr($url,-2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$url='http://www.domain.com/2/,http://www.domain.com/3/';
if(is_numeric (substr($url,-2,1))){
 echo "This is number";
}else{
  echo "This is not number";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to get offtopic, but when i'm dealing with URLs usually i delete ending slashes using

```
 $url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Usually you won't need that slash and it'll be messy when exploding the URL. You can use the substr() function as mentioned by previous answers to get the last character of the string then. AFAIK the substr() function is faster than using regular expressions for such a simple task.

```
 if (is_numeric(substr($url, -1)) {}
```

**edit**

i just realized that if you are dealing with values > 9 you will be in trouble. 
Better get the whole number as mentioned in another answer. If you prefer strange looking code with slightly better performance you can use that one instead of explode():

```
 $value = strrev(strtok(strrev($url), '/'));
 if (is_numeric($value)) {}
```